# Как добавить select в расчёты калькулятора стоимости

Tags: javascript, php, html

Делаю калькулятор стоимости на JS. Всё получается, но никак не хочет выводиться select в итоговую стоимость. Подскажите, как выводить option из select в итоговую стоимость

Код формы:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Онлайн калькулятор
*/
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Калькулятор</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fill"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <form action="#" class="form form1">
        <div class="form__item">
          <h2 class="heading">Тип фальшбалки</h2>
          <ul class="switcher">
            <li class="switcher__item">
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="tipbalki"
                id="gobraz"
                class="tipbalki"
                value="gobraz"
              />
              <label for="gobraz">Г - образная</label>
            </li>
            <li class="switcher__item">
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="tipbalki"
                id="pobraz"
                class="tipbalki"
                value="pobraz"
                checked="checked"
              />
              <label for="pobraz">П - образная</label>
            </li>
            <li class="switcher__item">
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="tipbalki"
                id="kolonna"
                class="tipbalki"
                value="kolonna"
              />
              <label for="kolonna">Колонна-Короб</label>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
          
          
          <div class="form__item">
          <h2 class="heading">Порода дерева</h2>
          <ul class="switcher">
            <li class="switcher__item">
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="poroda"
                id="sosna"
                class="poroda"
                value="sosna"
              />
              <label for="sosna">Сосна</label>
            </li>
            <li class="switcher__item">
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="poroda"
                id="listvennica"
                class="poroda"
                value="listvennica"
                checked="checked"
              />
              <label for="listvennica">Лиственница</label>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
          
          <div class="form__item">
          <h2 class="heading">Нужно красить?</h2>
          <ul class="switcher">
            <li class="switcher__item">
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="kraska"
                id="da"
                class="kraska"
                value="da"
              />
              <label for="da">Да</label>
            </li>
            <li class="switcher__item">
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="kraska"
                id="net"
                class="kraska"
                value="net"
                checked="checked"
              />
              <label for="net">Нет</label>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
          
           <div class="form__item">
          <h2 class="heading">Дополнительные опции</h2>
          <ul class="switcher">
            <li class="switcher__item">
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="dop"
                id="net2"
                class="dop"
                value="net2"
              />
              <label for="net2">Нет</label>
            </li>
            <li class="switcher__item">
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="dop"
                id="brashirovka"
                class="dop"
                value="brashirovka"
                checked="checked"
              />
              <label for="brashirovka">Брашировка балок</label>
            </li>
              
              <li class="switcher__item">
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="dop"
                id="rublennye"
                class="dop"
                value="rublennye"
                checked="checked"
              />
              <label for="rublennye">Рубленные "под топор" балки</label>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
          
          
          
          
        <div class="form__item">
          <h2 class="heading">Выберите размер балки из списка:</h2>
          <ul class="switcher">
              <li class="switcher__item">
              <select onchange="selspUpdate" id="type_services">
                        <option value="0">Выбрать</option>
                        <option value="711">50*50 мм</option>
                        <option value="897">75*75 мм</option>
                        <option value="1030">100*100 мм</option>
                        <option value="1136">120*120 мм</option>
                </select>
              
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
          
          <div class="form__item">
          <h2 class="heading">Укажите длину балки и количество балок:</h2>
          <div class="slider">
            <input
              type="number"
              placeholder="Длина, м"
              name="dlina"
              id="dlina"
              step="1"
              min="2"
              max="96"
            />
              <output id="volume5" for="dlina">2</output>
          
              <input
              type="number"
              placeholder="Количество"
              name="kolichestvo"
              id="kolichestvo"
              step="1"
              min="2"
              max="96"
            />
            <output id="volume6" for="kolichestvo">2</output>
          </div>
        </div>
          
          
        
      </form>
      <form action="#" class="form form2">
        <div class="form__item">
          <h2 class="heading">Ваш заказ</h2>
          <div class="order">
            <span>Тип фальшбалки:</span>
            <output id="order_tipbalki">—</output>
          </div>
            <div class="order">
            <span>Порода дерева:</span>
            <output id="order_poroda">—</output>
          </div>
            <div class="order">
            <span>Нужно красить?</span>
            <output id="order_kraska">—</output>
          </div>
            <div class="order">
            <span>Дополнительные опции:</span>
            <output id="order_dop">—</output>
          </div>
          <div class="order">
            <span>Сторона 1, мм:</span>
            <output id="order_storona1">—</output>
          </div>
            <div class="order">
            <span>Сторона 2, мм:</span>
            <output id="order_storona2">—</output>
          </div>
            <div class="order">
            <span>Сторона 3, мм:</span>
            <output id="order_storona3">—</output>
          </div>
            <div class="order">
            <span>Сторона 4, мм:</span>
            <output id="order_storona4">—</output>
          </div>
            <div class="order">
            <span>Длина балки, м:</span>
            <output id="order_dlina">—</output>
          </div>
            <div class="order">
            <span>Количество балок:</span>
            <output id="order_kolichestvo">—</output>
          </div>
           </div>
        <div class="form__item">
          <h2 class="heading">Итоговая стоимость</h2>
          <output class="total" id="total">0</output>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Код JS:

```
const tipbalki = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".tipbalki"));
const poroda = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".poroda"));
const kraska = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".kraska"));
const dop = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dop"));
const option = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".option"));
const dlina = document.querySelector("#dlina");
const kolichestvo = document.querySelector("#kolichestvo");
const volume5 = document.querySelector("#volume5");
const volume6 = document.querySelector("#volume6");
const total = document.querySelector("#total");

const orderTipbalki = document.querySelector("#order_tipbalki");
const orderPoroda = document.querySelector("#order_poroda");
const orderKraska = document.querySelector("#order_kraska");
const orderDop = document.querySelector("#order_dop");
const orderDlina = document.querySelector("#order_dlina");
const orderKolichestvo = document.querySelector("#order_kolichestvo");
const orderOption = document.querySelector("#order_option");
tipbalki.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", tipbalkiUpdate);
});

poroda.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", porodaUpdate);
});

kraska.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", kraskaUpdate);
});

dop.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", dopUpdate);
});



dlina.addEventListener("input", dlinaUpdate);
kolichestvo.addEventListener("input", kolichestvoUpdate);

option.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("change", optionUpdate);
});

function tipbalkiUpdate(e) {
  currentSet.tipbalki = e.target.id;
  updatePrice();
  orderUpdate();
}

function porodaUpdate(e) {
  currentSet.poroda = e.target.id;
  updatePrice();
  orderUpdate();
}

function kraskaUpdate(e) {
  currentSet.kraska = e.target.id;
  updatePrice();
  orderUpdate();
}

function dopUpdate(e) {
  currentSet.dop = e.target.id;
  updatePrice();
  orderUpdate();
}




function dlinaUpdate(e) {
  currentSet.dlina = dlina.value;
  volume5.value = currentSet.dlina;
  updatePrice();
  orderUpdate();
}
function kolichestvoUpdate(e) {
  currentSet.kolichestvo = kolichestvo.value;
  volume6.value = currentSet.kolichestvo;
  updatePrice();
  orderUpdate();
}

function optionUpdate(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (e.target.checked) {
    currentSet.option.push(e.target.id);
  } else {
    let index = currentSet.option.indexOf(e.target.id);
    currentSet.option.splice(index, 1);
  }
  updatePrice();
  orderUpdate();
}

function updatePrice() {
  let tipbalkiPrice = currentSet.getTipbalkiPrice();
  let porodaPrice = currentSet.getPorodaPrice();
  let kraskaPrice = currentSet.getKraskaPrice();
  let dopPrice = currentSet.getDopPrice();
  let optionPrice = currentSet.getOptionPrice();
  let totalPrice = currentSet.dlina * currentSet.kolichestvo + tipbalkiPrice + optionPrice + porodaPrice + kraskaPrice + dopPrice;
  total.value = totalPrice;
}

function orderUpdate() {
    if (currentSet.dlina < 5) {
    orderDlina.value = currentSet.dlina + " часа";
  } else {
    orderDlina.value = currentSet.dlina + " часов";
  }
    if (currentSet.kolichestvo < 5) {
    orderKolichestvo.value = currentSet.kolichestvo + " часа";
  } else {
    orderKolichestvo.value = currentSet.kolichestvo + " часов";
  }
  orderTipbalki.value = currentSet.getTipbalkiPrice() + " \u{20BD}/час";
  orderPoroda.value = currentSet.getPorodaPrice() + " \u{20BD}/час";
  orderKraska.value = currentSet.getKraskaPrice() + " \u{20BD}/час";
  orderDop.value = currentSet.getDopPrice() + " \u{20BD}/час";
  orderOption.value = currentSet.getOptionPrice() + " \u{20BD}";
}


const priceInfo = {
  tipbalki: {
    gobraz: 0,
    pobraz: 0,
    kolonna: 0,
  },
  poroda: {
    sosna: 0,
    listvennica: 0,
  },
  kraska: {
    da: 1000,
    net: 0,
  },
  dop: {
    net2: 0,
    brashirovka: 1000,
    rublennye: 1000,
  },
  option: {
    option1: 0,
    option2: 0,
    option3: 0,
    option4: 0,
  },
};

 let currentSet = {
  tipbalki: "pobraz",
  poroda: "sosna",
  kraska: "da",
  dop: "net2",
  dlina: 0,
  kolichestvo: 0,
  option: [],
  getTipbalkiPrice() {
    return priceInfo.tipbalki[this.tipbalki];
  },
    getPorodaPrice() {
    return priceInfo.poroda[this.poroda];
  },
    getKraskaPrice() {
    return priceInfo.kraska[this.kraska];
  },
    getDopPrice() {
    return priceInfo.dop[this.dop];
  },
     
  getOptionPrice() {
    let optionPrice = 0;
    if (!this.option.length == 0) {
      this.option.forEach((el) => {
        optionPrice += priceInfo.option[el];
      });
    }
    return optionPrice;
  }, 
 
};
```

[image: Калькулятор]

Answer (score 0):

`Value` задаются у `<option>`ов, но берутся у `<select>`а:

```html
<select id="type_services">
  <option value="0">Выбрать</option>
  <option value="711">50*50 мм</option>
  <option value="897">75*75 мм</option>
  <option value="1030">100*100 мм</option>
  <option value="1136">120*120 мм</option>
</select>

<button onclick="console.log(document.getElementById('type_services').value)" ;>Show</button>
```